# Name this church in Moscow, please?

Tags: sightseeing, identify-this, architecture, religion

I'm trying to type up my notes of Moscow, and can't seem to find the name of this church I took a photo of.  After using google image search, however, I refound a photo of it at [this location](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/5aOGdZvINRSxVmNKSQi9NQ) so have a latitude and longitude there, but no name.  Can anyone help with this treasure hunt? :)

[image: church]

Comment: I take pictures of signs. Many, many pictures of signs. They are super helpful for identifying the subjects of the surrounding pictures when I get home. Some of them have value of their own as well, but most are just notes to myself. For example the Venice churches all had standard nameplates on the outside and I took pictures of them knowing the churches would start to blur together for me.

Comment: I normally do but was hunting for a hostel at the time and didn't think to do it.  Def the best way to remember - can't always rely on the mind ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's my guess...

**Trinity Church, in Serebryaniki**

Source: http://www.panoramio.com/photo/6837647 ([translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http://www.panoramio.com/photo/6837647&hl=en&langpair=auto%7Cen&tbb=1&ie=UTF-8))

Comment: You sir, are a legend! Can confirm that street name rings a vivid bell now too.  Many thanks!

Comment: @Mark Mayo Actually I don't know every church in Moscow. And I even didn't see this question 5 hours ago, so no, I'm not upset. I'll just remove this answer, and add it by myself. Mwahahaha.

Comment: @Mark Mayo - you did the hard part finding the longitude and latitude! Glad I could help.

Comment: my source says "Church of the Life-Giving Trinity in the Serebryankiy (Silversmith Quarters) with the Bell Tower and Church of the Beheading of John the Baptist " 
http://wikimapia.org/#lat=55.750206&lon=37.644054&z=18&l=0&m=b&show=/1610580/Church-of-the-Life-Giving-Trinity-in-the-Serebryankiy-Silversmith-Quarters-with-the-Bell-Tower-and-Church-of-the-Beheading-of-John-the-Baptist